# Why seat belts, and not five-point harnesses?

Tags: safety, automobiles, child-safety-seats

For car travel, it is mandatory in many countries that small children be strapped in carseats with a multi-point harness system. However, I have not seen such a system for adults in a normal (ie non-racing) passenger vehicle.

What are the reasons against mandating such systems instead of seat belts? Is it because of political difficulties, or are there safety reasons too?

Comment: Small children can slip out from normal seatbelts while adults can't? normal seatbelts can cause a huge pressure on chest and abdomen which adults can handle but children can't?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't specific to international travel, it applies equally to people who just drive a car 4 miles to workplace or shops.

Comment: Maybe https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ would be better place to ask?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: While I agree that not every transportation question is necessarily a _travel_ question, there's nothing to indicate that this site is exclusively about _international_ travel.

Comment: The extra gain in safety is small compared to the hassle and technical overhead to implement them - a five-point-harness doesn't help you if you hit a bridge post with 60 mph (100km/h).

Comment: I voted to re-open the question. I think it's 100% on topic.

Comment: A five-point harness would be complicated to size correctly for adults too--much more variation in height. Think about having to reposition the shoulder straps to fit someone over six feet versus someone closer to five feet.

Comment: @mkennedy wrong, just check pilots and cabin crew seats...

Comment: If the question about train seatbelts was on-topic, I see no reason why this one wouldn't be.

Comment: The answer is that there is no seatbelt lobby that has successfully campaigned to get such a law passed. Without it being required by law, it's not going to happen. I too think this is off topic, same as the train seatbelts question.

Comment: The closest thing listed as on-topic is "modes of travelling: international, domestic, and public transport".  This is realistically not about any of those whereas the train question falls under public transport.

Comment: I'm looking for published research and haven't found any yet, but I'd speculate that the more complicated the restraint system is to use, the greater the fraction of people who won't use it at all.  (There's already a non-negligible fraction of people who don't use existing three-point seat belts.)  That might actually lead to a net increase in the number of deaths / injuries.  There'd also have to be a cost-benefit analysis to decide if the increased safety was enough to justify a more expensive harness.

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree, and I'd also argue that the more complicated the system is to use, the greater the fraction of people who will use it improperly. Some people will inevitably fasten only the lower portion and not the shoulder straps, and I'd presume that's more dangerous than just wearing a standard three-point seatbelt properly.

Comment: @ZachLipton These are valid reasons (I guess). However, why don't they apply to child seats?

Comment: @el.pescado This question has nothing to do with vehicle maintenance, so it's off-topic at [mechanics.se].

Comment: Your question is "Why does the law say X instead of Y?" That's a question about [politics.se].

Comment: @BorisBukh I'd say they do apply to child seats: ["A 2016 report by the {US} National Highway Traffic Safety Administration found that up to 59 percent of car seats were improperly used."](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/20/well/family/you-may-be-using-your-childs-car-seat-incorrectly.html)